# How to temporarily disable local forwards

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have in my `~/.ssh/config` file entries with local forward definitions like

```
HOST myServer
   hostname 10.10.0.1
   user xyz
   LocalForward 8080 localhost:80
   LocalForward 4000 127.0.0.1:4000
   ...
```

This works like a charm, but I also have scripts to synchronize some data.
These scripts show many warnings when they try to connect to the server while there is already a connection.

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 4000
....
```

Is there a *neat* way to use `ssh` or `rsync` with an option to disable all local forwards for a session?

Obviously I could copy&paste each config block and build one with and one without local forwards, but I hope there is a better solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is `ClearAllForwardings` option in `ssh_config`, which does exactly what you need:

> **ClearAllForwardings**
>
> Specifies that all local, remote, and dynamic port forwardings specified in the configuration files or on the command line be cleared.  This option is primarily useful when used from the
>   ssh(1) command line to clear port forwardings set in configuration files, and is automatically set by scp(1) and sftp(1).  The argument must be yes or no (the default).

You can use it as a commandline option:

```
ssh -o ClearAllForwardings=yes host
```

Comment: Perfect - I thought that I have read the documentation carefully enough

Comment: Just in case anyone is needing this with `git`: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="/usr/bin/ssh -o ClearAllForwardings=yes"`

Comment: Definitely not `RemoteForward=no` -- which is the kind of thing that I was searching for when looking for the same answer.

Comment: This also suppresses the message `Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port XYZ` when there is already a connection.

Comment: @Jan when the forwarding is disabled, it can not obviously fail.

Comment: Can we fix the answer? it's the lower case `o` not the big `O`.

Comment: @wbkang sure. Fixed now. Sorry, it was probably typo.